# Pagination in ListView's present in three different Fragments which is in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, pagination, android-viewpager

I am having an issue with **Pagination** of a **ListView** which is present in `**Each Fragment**` that is inside a `ViewPager`. I initially have to show 10 records in first Fragment which is **"All"**, from this sort out **"Failed"** and show it in second Fragment and **"Passed"** in third fragment. How can I implement Pagination in this? I should be  having a **`"Load More"`** Button and whenever user clicks on it I should get the next 10 records. I have tried to search but couldn't find anything that serves my purpose. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand the "listview is present in each fragment". Do you mean that the number of records displayed are the same?

So if the first fragment displays 10 records and 5 are failed and another 5 are passed the second and third fragment would only display 5 records?

You don't need the same listView for that, I will guide you through the process of building this thing. Lets go!

I'm going to assume that getting the records isn't a problem, and for the purposes of this answer I'm going to assume that a record is an object with two properties: String content and boolean passed, that can be retrieved by the methods isPassed() and getContent().

First lets take care of the activity that calls the fragments and add a couple of important methods:

```js
{...}
  private int listSize = 10;  

  public void addMoreToList(){
    listSize +=10;
  }

  public void getListSize(){
    return listSize;
  }

  //replace this method and all its implementations with your own way of getting the records
 public List<Record> getRecords(){
    return recordList;
   }

 
 {...}
```

Ok, so now our main activity can store and retrieve the number of records, lets get to the bigger guns, our adapter!

```js
private class RecordAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
  
  public static final int MODE_ALL = 0;
  public static final int MODE_PASSED = 1;
  public static final int MODE_FAILED = 2;
  
  private int mode;
  private Context context;
  private List<Records> records;
  
  public RecordAdapter(Context context, int mode){
    this.context = context;
    this.mode = mode;
    }
  
  public void setData(List<Records> totalList, int size){
    //this will add from the records list the size we want
    //if that size is smaller than the total size of the list
    //or else we'd get an error :(
    for(int i = 0; i <  (totalList.size() < size ? size: totalList.size()); i++){
      switch(mode){
       case(MODE_ALL): 
        records.add(totalList.get(i))
        break;
       case(MODE_PASSED):
        if(totalLost.get(i).isPassed()){
          records.add(totalLost.get(i)
        }
        break;
       case(MODE_FAILED):
        if(!totalLost.get(i).isPassed()){
          records.add(totalLost.get(i));
        }
        break;
       }
     }
    notifyDatasetChanged(); //i almost forgot this one, heh, its very important.
   }
    
  @Override 
  public Object getItem(int position){
    return records.get(position)
  }
  
  @Override
  public int getCount(){
    return records.size();
  }
      
  @Override
  public int getItemId(int position){
    return position;
  }
  
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view;
    if(convertView == null){
      view =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.yourtextview, parent, false); //I'm assuming here you 
      //only want a textview to display the text
    }else{
      view = convertView;
    }
    
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
    Record record = records.get(position)
    textView.setText(record.getContent());
    
    return view;
 }
}
```

We're almost there! Now for our fragments. First the xml:

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ListView
        android:id = "@+id/lv_records"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "0 dp"           
        />
     
</LinearLayout>
```

```js
private RecordsAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xmlabove, container, false);

  ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_records);
  

  //This is just an example. You can inflate a view from an xml if you want fancy format
  //and etc. You could also define an onClickListener directly in the button and add it
  //to the listView, but i think this design is more appropriate.
  Button button = new Button(getActivity());
  button.setText("Load more...");
  listView.addFooterView(button);
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
          if(position < ((RecordsAdapter) parent).getCount()){
            //code for regular record click here
          }else{
           //means the position is not in the adapter, it's our button
           ((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).addMoreToList();        
            adapter.setData(((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).getRecords(),    
                  ((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).getListSize());
          }
        }

  });
  adapter = new RecordsAdapter(context, RecordsAdapter.MODE_NORMAL); //replace each mode on each fragment
  
  adapter.setData(((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).getRecords(), ((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).getListSize());

  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  
  return view; 

@Override
public void onResume(){
  super.onResume();
  //in case there was a change of listsize in another fragment, we want this adapter to update when we return
  //to this fragment.
  adapter.setData(((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).getRecords(), ((YourActivityNameHere)getActivity()).getListSize());
  }
```

After all that you should have a functioning implementation of what you want!

Also, bear in mind that i just coded all that out of the top of my head, no ide, some bugs are probably lurking in the code, so read it before using it. I can't really re-read it right now.

Hope i was of help!

Comment: I have to add the Load More button to listview as footer dynamically. Not in Xml file

Comment: Jeez, picky picky. Ok, lets do it then, give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Edited with the changes, it should be functional now. Don't forget to debug the code, come back to me if something fails.

Comment: the code which you gave in activity class... I am doing that in Frgaments to fetch data. Can I still follow this procedure?

Comment: OnItemClickListener won't work in my case because my adapter view has some images and buttons for which there is an action in the adapter class.

Comment: About using fragments, you can follow this procedure yes, just change whatever needs change. About the listener it should still work. Listeners added in the adapter have priority, but if the click event isn't caught by any listener, it should still trigger onItemClickListener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63093/discussion-between-rosalie-and-jvrodrigues).